# Binary Search Tree Deconstructor

Tags: c++, memory, binary-search-tree

Below I have posted the code I am trying to use to create a deconstructor for a binary search tree. If I eliminate the attempts at linking the parents to NULL before the node is deleted the code runs perfectly (it will not run forever and correctly deletes the nodes). However, from what I am to understand the pointers are now pointing to garbage data and not NULL. How do I fix this or what is wrong with my attempt to fix this? (The error I get is "unable to read memory").

```
  int BinarySearchTree::postOrderTreeDelete(PhoneInfo * x)
{
    static int counter = 0;

        if (x == NULL)
        {
            return counter;
        }

        else
        {
            postOrderTreeDelete(x->getLeft());
            postOrderTreeDelete(x->getRight());

            //deleten(x);
            if (x == x->getParent()->getLeft())
                x->getParent()->setLeft(NULL);
            else if (x == x->getParent()->getRight())
                x->getParent()->setRight(NULL);

            delete x;
            counter++;
        }
        postOrderTreePrint();
        return counter;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the tree has, say, just 2 or 3 levels?  Did you use your debugger to debug the issue?

Comment: Mentioning "postOrder" in the function name is pointless since that's the only reasonable way to delete the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you're destroying the tree anyway, why create all the intermediate stages of the tree as you go?

Just this should be sufficient:

```
int BinarySearchTree::postOrderTreeDelete(PhoneInfo * x)
{
    if (!x)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int counter = 1; // for x
        counter += postOrderTreeDelete(x->getLeft());
        counter += postOrderTreeDelete(x->getRight());

        delete x;
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this *in* the destructor, and get rid of the returned count altogether:

```
BinarySearchTree::~BinarySearchTree()
{
    delete _left;
    delete _right;
}
```

Then the caller just has to use the `delete` operator.

If you're deleting a node there's no need to also zero its data members. No need to polish the garbage before you throw it out.